# Python Regex Multiline, finds lines starting with 00, but not 20

Tags: regex, python-3.x, multiline

I have a python script(below) that is supposed to find lines in a text file starting with 00 and 20, then output the lines to two separate files, one for 00, and one for 20. It works just fine on output1, but produces an empty tuple for output2. What am I doing wrong? The lines in the text file are all the same, no special characters, and it either starts with a 00 or 20.

```
import sys
import re
import glob
import os

listfiles = glob.glob('*.txt')



def DataExtract(inputfilename):
    myfilename1 = open('00 extract ' + inputfilename,'w')
    myfilename2 = open('20 extract ' + inputfilename,'w')

    with open(inputfilename, 'r') as f:
         output1 = re.findall(r'^00.*', f.read(), re.MULTILINE)
         output2 = re.findall(r'^20.*', f.read(), re.MULTILINE)

    wout1 = "\n".join(output1)
    wout2 = "\n".join(output2)
    print (wout2)
    print (output2)
    myfilename1.write(wout1)
    myfilename2.write(wout2)
    myfilename1.close
    myfilename2.close


for n in listfiles:
    DataExtract(n)
```

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Why do you read the file twice? I think you can just read line by line and use `if line.startswith('20')` / `if line.startswith('00')` and write to the appropriate files.

Comment: Why not just loop over the lines in the file and check `if line.startswith(('00', '20'))`?

Comment: Hmmm, still pretty new with python. I will try this, thank you.

Comment: Files are stream based. After first `read()` the fileposition is after its data - so the second read reads nothing.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I did not know this, thank you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked just perfectly, thank you

Comment: @ctwheels Im not sure if that would work since I need to output to separate files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `f.read()` the second time, there is nothing more to read as the first `f.read()`  alread consumed the file stream. Thus, you might solve the issue if you read the file into a variable and then used it instead of the `f.read()`, but since you are working with literal texts, you might just as well read the file line by line and use a `str.startswith()` check:

```
def DataExtract(inputfilename):
    myfilename1 = open('00 extract ' + inputfilename,'w')
    myfilename2 = open('20 extract ' + inputfilename,'w')

    with open(inputfilename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('00'):
                myfilename1.write(line)
            elif line.startswith('20'):
                myfilename2.write(line)

    myfilename1.close()
    myfilename2.close()
```